# Authentication/Authorization in ASP.NET Core using Enterprise SingleSignon page and Microsoft SignInManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, single-sign-on

Presently I am working on an authentication issue in one of my ASP.NET Core(3.0) application.

To give some background, we have to use an Enterprise Single sign on page to authenticate the users. Once the user got authenticated it redirects back to our application along with user name in a HTTP header called "SM_USER". Then using that information we load corresponding Claim information from DB using Microsoft SignInManger. The application is working fine if the user is accessing the root but it couldn't able to access if they are trying to navigate a specific page directly, like http://website/Controller/Index.

I am suspecting that we may have implemented it wrongly so would like to know how should the below scenario to be implemented?

*Our users first get authenticated using an enterprise Login Page(Single sign on) then redirected to our application. user information available on HTTP Headers and the corresponding claims information is available in our DB which we need to use for authorization purpose(we wanted to use Microrosoft SignInManger to load them).*

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue after researching it throughly so sharing here in case it useful for someone.

we observed whenever a user try to access a page if the user is not authenticated then it is redirecting Login page(Observed that decorating them with [Authorize] attribute is causing this), where We are using this Login page for local development purpose.

so when the user get redirected to login page and if the environment is not development then below code is executed on the Get method, which takes care of signing the user and creating UserPrincipal. Then after that we redirecting to the page the user requested.

```
if (!_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
            {
                string userName = HttpContext.Request.Headers["SM_USER"].ToString();
                if (userName.Length > 0)
                {
                    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        var claimsPrincipal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
                        await _signInManager.Context.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
                            claimsPrincipal,
                            new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true });

                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) //returnUrl is a parameter get passed by the system. 
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("<Action>", "<Controller>");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return Redirect(returnUrl);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```